# How to know when a full DMS reload began via CloudWatch logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-dms, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

The [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Monitoring.html) describes a Task Status of "Starting", however searching that in the CloudWatch results in a lot of noise.  Is there a targeted CloudWatch search which will retrieve the start dates of a full DMS reload?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that dms logging only uses the term `"fresh start"` at the beginning of a replication task re/start, however, more digging may be required to differentiate between the task start types of "start-replication", "resume-processing" and "reload-target".

Alternativly, you could use the [aws dms sns event subscriptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Events.html) and subscribe to alerts when a task state changes.